# Applying an operation on multiple columns with a fixed column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe as shown below. The last column shows the sum of values from all the columns i.e. `A`,`B`,`D`,`K` and `T`. Please note some of the columns have `NaN` as well.

```
word1,A,B,D,K,T,sum
na,,63.0,,,870.0,933.0
sva,,1.0,,3.0,695.0,699.0
a,,102.0,,1.0,493.0,596.0
sa,2.0,487.0,,2.0,15.0,506.0
su,1.0,44.0,,136.0,214.0,395.0
waw,1.0,9.0,,34.0,296.0,340.0
```

How can I calculate the entropy for each row? i.e. I should find something like following

```
df['A']/df['sum']*log(df['A']/df['sum']) + df['B']/df['sum']*log(df['B']/df['sum']) + ...... + df['T']/df['sum']*log(df['T']/df['sum'])
```

The condition is that whenever the value inside the `log` becomes `zero` or `NaN`, the whole value should be treated as zero (by definition, the log will return an error as log 0 is undefined).

I am aware of using lambda operation to apply on individual columns. Here I am not able to think for a pure pandas solution where a fixed column `sum` is applied on different columns `A`,`B`,`D` etc.. Though I can think of a simple loopwise iteration over CSV file with hard-coded column values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) for selecting columns from `A` to `T`, then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`numpy.log`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html). Last use [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
print (df['A']/df['sum']*np.log(df['A']/df['sum']))
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3   -0.021871
4   -0.015136
5   -0.017144
dtype: float64

print (df.ix[:,'A':'T'].div(df['sum'],axis=0)*np.log(df.ix[:,'A':'T'].div(df['sum'],axis=0)))
          A         B   D         K         T
0       NaN -0.181996 NaN       NaN -0.065191
1       NaN -0.009370 NaN -0.023395 -0.005706
2       NaN -0.302110 NaN -0.010722 -0.156942
3 -0.021871 -0.036835 NaN -0.021871 -0.104303
4 -0.015136 -0.244472 NaN -0.367107 -0.332057
5 -0.017144 -0.096134 NaN -0.230259 -0.120651

print((df.ix[:,'A':'T'].div(df['sum'],axis=0)*np.log(df.ix[:,'A':'T'].div(df['sum'],axis=0)))
         .sum(axis=1))
0   -0.247187
1   -0.038471
2   -0.469774
3   -0.184881
4   -0.958774
5   -0.464188
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, :-1]
df2 = df1.div(df1.sum(1), axis=0)
df2.mul(np.log(df2)).sum(1)

word1
na    -0.247187
sva   -0.038471
a     -0.469774
sa    -0.184881
su    -0.958774
waw   -0.464188
dtype: float64
```

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """word1,A,B,D,K,T,sum
na,,63.0,,,870.0,933.0
sva,,1.0,,3.0,695.0,699.0
a,,102.0,,1.0,493.0,596.0
sa,2.0,487.0,,2.0,15.0,506.0
su,1.0,44.0,,136.0,214.0,395.0
waw,1.0,9.0,,34.0,296.0,340.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), index_col=0)

df
```

[image]